# The meaning of os.system in python

Tags: python

I am working to convert a code which is written in a code called " elegant" into another code.

I come by this lines, which i could not understand well, i am quit new to python

```
import os,sys
def computeOpticsD(quad_name, quad_id,k1):
    ex = '/Users/ia/Products/elegant/darwin-x86/elegant'
    args =  ' compute_optics_d.ele -macro=lattice=fodo,quad_name='+quad_name+',quad_id='+str(quad_id)+',k1='+str(k1)
    args += ',dir=data'
    os.system(ex + args)
```

What dose it exactly do ?

Comment: os.system runs a command line through the python itself. If you tried the value inside the `ex+args` in your command prompt (also known as shell, if I am correct), you can see the result would be the same as you run the code in the `computeOpticsD` function in python.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` allow you to run OS commands as you would do for example in a script  or in the terminal directly.

For example, if you run `os.system("ls")` it will return the list of files and directories in the location

In this case it seems your code fragment is trying to execute the following command in the OS:

```
/Users/ia/Products/elegant/darwin-x86/elegant compute_optics_d.ele -macro=lattice={fodo}, quad_name={quad_name}, quad_id={quad_id}, k1={k1}, dir=data
```

Where the elemnts in the key brakets come from your method parameters as defined in: `def computeOpticsD(quad_name, quad_id,k1)`